# Bind Label's Position with Slider's Value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, slider

I have an slider control in an canvas like this:
[image]

I add a **label** (which is placed in a **border**) to the **canvas**. How can I **bind** this border's position, so that when **slider** value moves along it's path, the **border** moves correctly and show the value with it's **label**.

Can anyone help? Any working idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manage the left margin of the border containing the label, and bind it to the slider's value. To transform the slider value into an appropiate margin you'll need to create a custom converter. Keep in mind that there is no "LeftMargin" property, you'll have to create a new margin from the slider's value and pass it to the border:

In your case I recommend you to create a converter and pass some parameters: top border margin (fixed so it moves in a straight line, could be bound to the slider's position too), min and max slider value and slider's width to scale to margin coordinates. It's not trivial...

Another way is to create a new component that inherits from slider and that incorporates the label, but you won't avoid the converter that way.

Comment: I found a solution to that. look at my answer

Comment: I've seen it, it's a good solution as long as the slider's value cannot be changed by any other way than with the mouse. If the value changes via code (I don't know if you support it) or with the keyboard, the label will not move accordingly.

Comment: yes. in this case it will not change by code. But I'm interested to see if there is a way to support changes via code, too.

Comment: Binding the border's margin to the slider's value through a converter will support any change: via code, keyboard and mouse.

Comment: slider's value is between 1360 to 1400.  What logic can be used to convert it?

Comment: Transform the difference (1400 - 1360) into a percentage and multiply that percetange by the width of the slider, add the minimum left margin of the border and you get the left margin.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using C# coding. However it may be better solutions but it works for me.
In the `ValueChanged` event of the slider I write these codes.

```
private void year_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (this.yearInfo == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Point position = Mouse.GetPosition(this.mapView); //mapView is the name of my canvas
    this.yearInfo.Margin = 
         new Thickness(0, 0, position.X - this.yearInfo.ActualWidth / 2.0, 45);
}
```